# Manually add the LWUIT plugin to netbeans

Tags: java, plugins, lwuit, netbeans-8

I have tried going to the plugin download center and I refreshed over 50 times over the course of a week and still i cannot see the LWUIT plugin for Java ME.

Is there a way for me to manually install this plugin without using the plugin download center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do it after a few hours...
go to this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/LWUIT/LWUIT_old.jar.zip , then open the NetBeans IDE and create a new MIDlet project. In the project side bar, go to resources and right-click. On the menu that shows up, click add library. Click edit. Click on add JAR/folder and point to where you extracted the jar file.